# Nodejs Azure storage blob service : getStats not working

Tags: node.js, azure, statistics, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I use NodeJS 'azure-storage' module (version: 0.3.3)

I would like to get global stats about azure storage blob service.

Of course, I wont query all blobs to calculate by hand the total amount of storage used.

So I think that using `blobService.getServiceStats` could help me. But this method return an error.

```
this.blobService.getServiceStats(function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
     console.info(error);
  } else {
    console.info(result);
  }
});
```

This result in the following error :

```
{ [Error: Value for one of the query parameters specifie
RequestId:51b156a6-0001-002d-765f-b4ebd5000000
Time:2014-10-17T12:40:59.1246311Z]
  code: 'InvalidQueryParameterValue',
  queryparametername: 'comp',
  queryparametervalue: 'stats',
  reason: '',
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: '51b156a6-0001-002d-765f-b4ebd5000000' }
```

This query parameter 'comp = stats' seems to be set by the SDK itself : [blobservice.js line 156](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L156)

What's wrong ? do you think I should open an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) ?

Do you know a (working) way to get global blob stats ?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of this operation. This operation tells you the information about `Geo Replication Status` on your blob storage account and not how much space you're occupying for blob storage. From on the REST API documentation for Get Service Stats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495326.aspx

> The Get Blob Service Stats operation retrieves statistics related to
>   replication for the Blob service. **It is only available on the
>   secondary location endpoint when read-access geo-redundant replication
>   is enabled for the storage account**.

If you're interested in calculating the storage size of blob storage, what you would want to do is enable storage analytics on your storage account. After storage analytics is enabled, you can then query `$MetricsCapacityBlob` table to find the blob storage size. You can read more about this table here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343264.aspx.

Now coming to the reason why you're getting this error is because this operation can only be called on the `secondary geo-location url [youraccountname]-secondary.blob.core.windows.net` of your storage account. My guess is that you're just going with the standard settings which basically tries to execute this operation on the `primary storage url [youraccountname].blob.core.windows.net`.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your detailled answer, I will accept it. (Analytics : Yet another way to pay ? ^^)

Comment: What do you mean by `Analytics : Yet another way to pay ?`?